# [苛々 ]{いらいら} versus [刺々 ]{いらいら}

Tags: kanji, homophonic-kanji

Is there any difference in meaning between using [苛々 ]{いらいら}  or  [刺々 ]{いらいら} to indicate annoyance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost nothing but the latter possibly reminds readers of the real 刺【とげ】 "thorn", or another reading of the kanji: 刺々【とげとげ】 "barbed".

Although いらいら came from an old word [いら](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/15334/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%82%89/) that means "thorn", it's almost always written as 苛々 when merely means "annoyed; irritated". (But maybe more prevalent in katakana イライラ nowadays.)

Answer (score 1):

刺々 is read とげとげ and 苛々 and 刺々 are usually written in hiragana or katakana.

いらいら means "disconcertedness, stew,and distraction etc" and it shows a one's emotion like so, for example, 私は、彼の無礼な態度にイライラした(I was stabby for his rude attitude.)

とげ means spine and とげとげ means "acridly", for example, 彼の態度はトゲトゲしている(His attitude is acrid).

Comment: +1 for "stabby".  :)